# Way to find specific implementation of some features in python?

Tags: python, cpython

Background: When I read source code today, I feel curious about `@staticmethod`, and I think this decorator can be implemented using a class which has a  `__get__` method. It indeed can be done, but it's not so efficient, so I think maybe python uses other ways such as complete it in C source code. I use grep and find it was mentioned in `funcobject.h`:

```
/* The classmethod and staticmethod types lives here, too */
PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) PyClassMethod_Type;
PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) PyStaticMethod_Type;

PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyClassMethod_New(PyObject *);
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyStaticMethod_New(PyObject *);
```

but it's just a header file and I don't know how to continue my explore.

So I'm here to question:

**When I want to get clear some feature's implementation, is there any effective method (or methods) routine I can follow?**

For example: how did python implement `sort()`, it use quick sort or merge sort? How long it will consume? O(nlogn) or O(n2)?

Comment: The header file doesn't include the implementation, that's in the c file. The implementation you're looking for can be found here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/funcobject.c

Comment: Python uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).